# I'm using 2 fullcalendar in my vue application, when i click on the calendar I have to click on the popup twice to close it

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

When I click on calendar it opens up the popup window with event details. but when I try to close it I have to click twice on the close button, it was working fine when I was using just one fullcalendar in my application. These are the properties set for both the calendars in vue app.

```
       FullCalendar( 
           ref="fullCalendar" 
           id="fullCalendar"
           :header="header" 
           :defaultView="defaultView" 
           :fixedWeekCount="fixedWeekCount"
           :eventLimit="eventLimit"
           :nowIndicator="nowIndicator"
           :eventSources="eventSources"
           @eventClick="eventClick"
           @dateClick="dateClick"
           :plugins="calendarPlugins" 
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, because both calendars have same properties, two popups may be opening at the same time. I suggest at least changing ref and id of calendars to distinguish them.

Comment: yes both my fullcalendars have different id and refs, i have just shared one of the two fullCalendar properties.